# Best way to host WCF services for SOA web application

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I'm developing a website which attempts to utilize the SOA pattern. The services service both the main web app as well as an HTML5 mobile app and native iPhone and Android apps through the use of a facade service to provide a simplified API.

The web app uses the Castle WCF Facility to connect to the services using basicHttpBinding.

I am finding performance slow. Especially if the site hasn't been hit for over half an hour. To remedy this I have changed the app pool recycling strategy to recycle after the app pool hits x% of the servers RAM.

My question is - what is the best way to host services in a setup like this? What is the best binding to use? Should I consider moving the services out of IIS altogether? I understand net.tcp is the fastest binding to use - would it be best to host the services as windows services using that?

Cheers

w://

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Internet Information Services Hosting Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751802.aspx)

[Creating high performance WCF services](http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx)

[Hosting WCF Services](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0701041)

Answer (score 2):

To pick a few points:

> host the services as windows services

That looses all the monitoring and managing facilities that IIS offers. Only an option when your code is 100% perfect in error handling and resource management.

> [that] net.tcp is the fastest binding

For a local LAN, behind the firewall that might be a good option. Note that on 1 Server, namedPipe is even faster.

You should be able to configure a 2nd endpoint on your services for internal use. But I would stay with IIS. On all but the latest version you'll need WAS

Comment: What does this mean "On all but the latest version you'll need WAS"?

Comment: I don't remember the exact versions but on IIS 6.x you'll need the WAS plugin to host anything other than HTTP